# Processing of the data from a big number of input files

Tags: bash, awk

My AWK script processes each log file from the folder "${results}, from which it looks for a pattern (a number occurred on the first line of ranking table) and then print it in one line together with the filename of the log:

```
awk '$1=="1"{sub(/.*\//,"",FILENAME); sub(/\.log/,"",FILENAME); printf("%s: %s\n", FILENAME, $2)}' "${results}"/*_rep"${i}".log
```

Here is the format of each log file, from which the number

> -9.14

should be taken

```
AutoDock Vina v1.2.3
#################################################################
# If you used AutoDock Vina in your work, please cite:          #
#                                                               #
# J. Eberhardt, D. Santos-Martins, A. F. Tillack, and S. Forli  #
# AutoDock Vina 1.2.0: New Docking Methods, Expanded Force      #
# Field, and Python Bindings, J. Chem. Inf. Model. (2021)       #
# DOI 10.1021/acs.jcim.1c00203                                  #
#                                                               #
# O. Trott, A. J. Olson,                                        #
# AutoDock Vina: improving the speed and accuracy of docking    #
# with a new scoring function, efficient optimization and       #
# multithreading, J. Comp. Chem. (2010)                         #
# DOI 10.1002/jcc.21334                                         #
#                                                               #
# Please see https://github.com/ccsb-scripps/AutoDock-Vina for  #
# more information.                                             #
#################################################################

Scoring function : vina
Rigid receptor: /home/gleb/Desktop/dolce_vita/temp/nsp5holoHIE.pdbqt
Ligand: /home/gleb/Desktop/dolce_vita/temp/active2322.pdbqt
Grid center: X 11.106 Y 0.659 Z 18.363
Grid size  : X 18 Y 18 Z 18
Grid space : 0.375
Exhaustiveness: 48
CPU: 48
Verbosity: 1

Computing Vina grid ... done.
Performing docking (random seed: -1717804037) ... 
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
***************************************************

mode |   affinity | dist from best mode
     | (kcal/mol) | rmsd l.b.| rmsd u.b.
-----+------------+----------+----------
   1        -9.14          0          0
   2       -9.109      2.002       2.79
   3       -9.006      1.772      2.315
   4       -8.925          2      2.744
   5       -8.882      3.592      8.189
   6       -8.803      1.564      2.092
   7       -8.507      4.014      7.308
   8        -8.36      2.489      8.193
   9       -8.356      2.529      8.104
  10        -8.33      1.408      3.841
```

It works OK for a moderate number of input log files (tested for up to 50k logs), but does not work for the case of big number of the input logs (e.g. with 130k logs), producing the following error:

```
./dolche_finito.sh: line 124: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long
```

How could I adapt the AWK script to be able processing any number of input logs?

Comment: for loop is good solution for this to iterate over file list

Comment: Why don't you filter your data using `grep` (using `grep -A 10` you can filter on something, adding the ten next lines too). On that, you can start using `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get a `/usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long` then you'll have to control the number of "files" that you supply to `awk`; the standard way to do that efficiently is:

```bash
results=. # ??? 
i=00001   # ???
output=   # ???

find "$results" -type f -name "*_rep$i.log" -exec awk '
    FNR == 1 {
        filename = FILENAME
        sub(/.*\//,"",filename)
        sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",filename)
    }
    $1 == 1 { printf "%s: %s\n", filename, $2 }
' {} + |
LC_ALL=C sort -t':' -k2,2g > "$results"/ranking_"$output"_rep"$i".csv
```

<sup>**edit:** appended the rest of the chain as asked in comment</sup>

**note:** you might need to specify other predicates to the `find` command if you don't want it to search the sub-folders of `$results` recursively

Comment: so i tried just to add find before my command e.g. find "$results" -type f -name "*_rep$i.log" -exec awk '$1=="1"{sub(/.*\//,"",FILENAME); sub(/\.log/,"",FILENAME); printf("%s: %s\n", FILENAME, $2)}'  > results.log              but it does not work

Comment: @MaîtreRenard The `find` command is dependent of your shell variables, so the problem is either `"$results"` or `"$i"` that's not set. Would you mind testing it with my updated code?

Comment: actually this is command that I am using in my bash script which works OK with small number of the log files (note I piped AWK to SORT additionally to sort the lines in the resulted csv file (after AWK processing): awk '$1=="1"{sub(/.*\//,"",FILENAME); sub(/\.log/,"",FILENAME); printf("%s: %s\n", FILENAME, $2)}' "${results}"/*_rep"${i}".log | LC_ALL=C sort -t':' -k2,2g > "${results}"/ranking_${output}_rep${i}.csv

Comment: could you please show in your answer how to connect it properly with find ? :-)

Comment: @MaîtreRenard you pipe it to `sort` like any other command; see updated code

Answer (score 2):

Note that your error message:

```
./dolche_finito.sh: line 124: /usr/bin/awk: Argument list too long
```

is from your shell interpreting line 124 in your shell script, not from awk - you just happen to be calling awk at that line but it could be any other tool and you'd get the same error. Google `ARG_MAX` for more information on it.

Assuming `printf` is a builtin on your system:

```
printf '%s\0' "${results}"/*_rep"${i}".log |
xargs -0 awk '...'
```

or if you need awk to process all input files in one call for some reason and your file names don't contain newlines:

```
printf '%s' "${results}"/*_rep"${i}".log |
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        ARGV[ARGC++] = $0
        next
    }
    ...
'
```

If you're using GNU awk or some other awk that can process NUL characters as the RS and your input file names might contain newlines then you could do:

```
printf '%s\0' "${results}"/*_rep"${i}".log |
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        ARGV[ARGC++] = $0
        next
    }
    ...
' RS='\0' - RS='\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

When using GNU `AWK` you might alter [ARGC and ARGV](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html) to command GNU `AWK` to read additional files, consider following simple example, let `filelist.txt` content be

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

and content of these files to be respectively `uno`, `dos`, `tres` then

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ARGV[NR+1]=$0;ARGC+=1;next}{print FILENAME,$0}' filelist.txt
```

gives output

```
file1.txt uno
file2.txt dos
file3.txt tres
```

Explanation: when reading first file i.e. where number of row in file (`FNR`) is equal number of row globally (`NR`) I add to `ARGV` line as value under key being number of row plus one, as `ARGV[1]` is already `filelist.txt` and I increase `ARGC` by 1, I instruct GNU `AWK` to then go to `next` line so no other action is undertaken. For other files I `print` filename followed by whole line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*